# What size factor-base for Lenstra Elliptic Curve factorization

Tags: elliptic-curves, factorization

I'm writing a program to factorize numbers using Lenstra Elliptic Curve Factorization.

According to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), I should pick some k with a lot of small factors and then take a random point and curve and attempt to raise that point to the k'th power (the article suggests a factorial, but it seems to me like a slightly better choice would be LCM(1..B) for some B just because I want to pick the next number which the group order is most likely to be divisible by).

I do this for lots of points until one of them fails because I can't take a modulo inverse because the number I'm trying to invert isn't relatively prime to n at which point I stop and return the factors.

But I don't know how to pick B. It seems critical that k shouldn't be too small and clearly should be at least 4th root of n (but probably much larger). But there has to be *some* upper bound. You can't pick a number so large you never even finish trying the first curve.

Is there a simple function which approximates the success probability from n (the number to be factored) and B?

Comment: see http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb102.pdf